# Akka.net EchoServer Example deadletter when closing connection

Tags: akka.net

I am getting the following deadletter when closing the connection with the Akka.Net TcpEchoService Example (http://getakka.net/docs/IO):

```
[INFO][2015-09-04 09:13:51 AM][Thread 0013][akka://system/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$b/1] Message ChannelAcceptable from NoSender to akka://system/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$b/1 was not delivered. 1 dead letters encountered.
```

Is this by design? Or is there something I can do to stop the deadletter from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Akka.NET uses the messages and actors to manage it's own behavior. For this reason, sometimes when you stop a connection or shutdown a system, some of the system's internal actors may die before they receive awaiting system messages - like in your case. It's not always a bad thing, rather a nature of asynchronous communication between actors.